# Create lists with values of comparisons between groups stored within a table in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as ;

```
Comparison Distance
A,B        2
A,C        30
A,D        32
A,E        34
B,C        31  
B,D        40
B,E        5
C,E        2
C,D        6
D,E        7
```

and I have two list such as ;

```
Group_1 <- c("A","B")
Group_2 <- c("C","D","E")
```

and I would like to generate three new lists where I put all the `Comparison` between the element in `Group_1` and `Group_2` in a **List1_G1vsG2**, one **List2_G1vsG1** with comparison within element of `Group_1` and on in **List3_G2vsG2** for comparison within elements of `Group_1`.

I shoul then get the following lists:

**List1_G1vsG2**

```
c(30,32,34,31,40)
```

**List2_G1vsG1**

```
c(2)
```

**List3_G2vsG2**

```
c(5,2,6,7)
```

Here is the dataframe in `dput()` format if it can help

```
structure(list(Comparison = c("A,B", "A,C", "A,D", "A,E", "B,C", 
"B,D", "B,E", "C,E", "C,D", "D,E"), Distance = c(2, 30, 32, 34, 
31, 40, 5, 2, 6, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate(Comparison, into = c("C1", "C2")) %>% 
  mutate(G = case_when(C1 %in% Group_1 & C2 %in% Group_1 ~ 1, 
                       C1 %in% Group_2 & C2 %in% Group_2 ~ 2,
                       C1 %in% Group_1 & C2 %in% Group_2 ~ 3)) %>% 
  group_by(G) %>% group_split %>% 
  map(pull, Distance) %>% set_names(c("List2_G1vsG1", "List3", "List1_G1vsG2"))

#> $List2_G1vsG1
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $List3
#> [1] 2 6 7
#> 
#> $List1_G1vsG2
#> [1] 30 32 34 31 40  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is beyond the scope of your request. You can customize a distance matrix computation function. By this way, you can determine whether or not the distance between A and B is equal to that of B and A.

```r
f <- function(x, y, dist.df){
  pair <- outer(x, y, paste, sep = ",")
  dist <- dist.df[[2]][match(pair, dist.df[[1]])]
  matrix(dist, length(x), dimnames = list(x, y))
}

f(Group_1, Group_2, df)
#    C  D  E
# A 30 32 34
# B 31 40  5

f(Group_1, Group_1, df)
#    A  B
# A NA  2
# B NA NA

f(Group_2, Group_2, df)
#    C  D  E
# C NA  6  2
# D NA NA  7
# E NA NA NA
```